# Customize merge commit message in Azure DevOps doesn't really work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

When completing a pull request in Azure DevOps, I do this:

[image]

But when I click on "complete merge", I see this:

[image]

What Gives?

Comment: A lot of history views show only the first line of the commit message, generally used as a kind of title or subject line - that's why it has a separate text box in your first screenshot. Viewing the individual commit will probably show the full body which you typed into the larger text area.

Answer (score 1):

I will see your changes in the commit details:

1. Updated commit message

[image]

2. Commit details:

[image]